# How to add custom option to ng-options output?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

i created a select in a table that get some email address from a list. Here is the code:

```
<td>
    <select ng-init="selectedEmail = selectedEmail ? selectedEmail : emails[0]" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedEmail" ng-options="item as item.dest for item in emails"></select>
</td>
```

I would add an additional option that would be a custom option for the final users. If i add `<option>` within `<select>` it is being overwritten by Angular `ng-options`

```
<td>
    <select ng-init="selectedEmail = selectedEmail ? selectedEmail : emails[0]" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedEmail" ng-options="item as item.dest for item in emails">
        <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

How can i add a custom option?

My purpose is to add a "custom" choice for the users: if they select that option they can write down their own choice, a custom text.

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312150/angularjs-add-a-static-option-with-ng-options

Comment: That solution introduces a blank option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.  If you want to continue using `ng-options` you can use a function.

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <select 
        ng-init="selectedEmail = selectedEmail ? selectedEmail : emails[0]"
        class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selectedEmail" 
        ng-options="item as item.dest for item in BuildList()"></select>
</td>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Custom Option" ng-model="customText" />
```

**Controller Function for BuildList**

```
$scope.BuildList = function() {

    if(!$scope.customText) {
       return $scope.emails;
    }
    var newList = angular.copy($scope.emails);
    newList.push({someobjectbuildUsingCustom});

    return newList ;
}
```

Comment: My purpose is to add a "Custom" choice for the users: if they select that option they can write down their own choice, a custom text (i have updated my question).

Comment: instead of "emails" in the ng-options attribute, uses a "getEmails" function that returns a different list depending on the context.

Comment: @smartmouse I updated my answer to build a list more like what you are looking for.  This will allow you to order the list however you would like

Comment: Nice job, thank you. Anyway i do not need to "store" the custom text in the array. It is an "one time" use of his custom text.

Comment: @smartmouse Because it is building new list it is only scoped to the drop down if you would remove null the custom value or reload the view it would not have the additional option.  So it isn't really saving anything to your `emails` object, If you would output emails on the page outside of the drop down it will not have your custom value

Comment: Ok, i'm trying to use your solution... so how to add an extra option in the HTML that set $scope.customText to `true` ?

Comment: Do you have a text field to enter custom text?  I updated my answer to include such an option.  If that model value is defined it would appear in the list.  If not how where you planning on identifying the user wanted to add a custom value?

Answer (score 2):

You can do as per below:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  {{sel}}
  <select ng-model="sel" ng-options="d.value as d.label for d in data">
    <option value="">any</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/qdw4Lvwo/3/) as well

Comment: It seems to be the solution, but please tell me why it works. For example, if i add a value to `value`, why it shows a blank options?

Comment: If you look at the generated html, the values are assigned by ng-options, you are adding a foreign value manually which interferes with the id's assigned by ng-options, this id's are the index in your data array. Hope it clarifies a bit for you.

Comment: Yes, it is clear. Is it possible to move the additional option at the end of the options list?

Comment: @smartmouse  No adding an option this way always put's the manually added options at the top of the list.

Comment: Guess you will have to push a custom option into the array from your controller.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this syntax :

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in emails" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
    <option ... custom option ...>...</option>
</select>
```